# InAppPurchase "Developer Removed from sale"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I am facing a problem. I have uploaded aan app to appstore and I have submitted the inapppurchase too for review.
But because of some reason I have removed from review and submitted new build for review. But this time I forgot the inapppurchase to set review it again.
Now my is Ready for sale but the inapppurchase is showing "Developer Removed from sale".
Please help me in this what should I have to do to approve my inapppurchase while the app is in ready for sale state?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Set correct entitlements and re-submit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that when you have cancelled the app from the review , it automatically changes status of inapp purchase of waiting for review to "Developer removed from sale".
When you submit the new binary and gets approved by apple, You have to go to inapp Purchase and you have to select the cleared for sale.

[image]

This is the trick!

Happy coding.

Comment: You also need to press the "edit" button first at the top of the In-App Purchases Summary

Comment: Setting to YES would it take effect immediately or is there another waiting process ?

Comment: There's a waiting process. Up to 8 hours apparently. I'm not this patient.

Answer (score 2):

From apple documentation: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html)

[image]